# Expose custom $errors on select directive inside multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a custom select directive `pets-select` that is used in multiple views and controllers. But I can't figure out how to pass in an optional `required` attribute and validate the outer form accordingly.

**How do I check whether the directive in use has `required` set to `true` and show an error message if a user doesn't select it?**

**Plunkr**
https://plnkr.co/edit/gDGWq32kxDnAv6ZYyke4?p=preview

**For example, the directive being used in one controller/view with a form name of `myForm`:**

```
  <!-- Main controller view -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
      <form name="myForm" ng-submit="mainCtrl.submit(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="mainCtrl.data.name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
          <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid">Please enter a name.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="mainCtrl.data.phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required="required">
          <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$invalid">Please enter a phone number.</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Custom select directive (how do I validate?) -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <pets-select ng-model="mainCtrl.data.pets" name="pets" label="Select pet" on-pet-change="mainCtrl.setPet(pet)" required="true"></pets-select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**Another controller/view with a form name of `anotherForm`:**

```
    <!-- Another controller and view -->
    <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl as anotherCtrl">
      <form name="anotherForm" ng-submit="anotherCtrl.submit(anotherForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="anotherCtrl.data.email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
          <div class="error" ng-show="anotherForm.email.$invalid">Please enter an email.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="anotherCtrl.data.address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required="required">
          <div class="error" ng-show="anotherForm.address.$invalid">Please enter an address.</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Custom select directive (how can i validate this?) -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <pets-select ng-model="anotherCtrl.data.pets" name="pets" label="Select pet" on-pet-change="anotherCtrl.setPet(pet)" required="false"></pets-select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**The directive definition:**

```
app.directive('petsSelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'pets-select.html',
    scope: {
      pet: '=ngModel',
      label: '@',
      onPetChange: '&',
      name: '@',
      required: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.pets = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Birds'];
    }
  };
});
```

**The directive template:**

```
<div class="select">
    <select ng-model="selectedPet" name="{{name}}" ng-change="onPetChange({pet: selectedPet})" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled">{{label}}</option>
      <option ng-repeat="pet in pets" value="{{pet}}">{{pet}}</option>
    </select>

    <!-- How do I check whether the directive in use is required and show this error message if a user doesn't select it?? -->
    <div ng-show="???">Please select a pet.</div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefer `ngMessages`,where you can add on field level error message. You can configure custom message if field is `required`.You can write your custom directive to validate and use to validate input

[Docs-ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

[Demo example-docs](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

P.S. Currently ,I am not able to work on your plunker but above resources will solve issue.